# Transaction is not being rollbacked in spring

Tags: spring, aop, transactionmanager

While issuing two inserts, if second one is failed the transaction should be rollback but this is not happening in my case, following are the details of configuration!

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.xyz.model.Merchant</value>
            ....
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="modify*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="allServices"
                  expression="execution(* 
    com.xyz.services.DemoApiServiceImpl.saveEmployee(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="allServices"/>
</aop:config>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

and these are the code details;

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DemoApiServiceImpl implements DemoApiService {

@Override
//@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class )
public boolean saveEmployee(Employee employee) throws Exception {

    Boolean flag = Boolean.FALSE;

    flag = demoApiDao.saveOrUpdateEmployee(employee);
    if(flag)
         //generating exception so that above insert should rollback!
        throw new Exception("ok");
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(employee.getUsers())) {
        Users user = (Users) employee.getUsers().toArray()[0];

        //sendEmail(user,EmailType.USER_SIGN_UP.name(),Constants.MAIL_SUBJECT_ACTIVATION_LINK);

        UsersDto usersDto = new UsersDto();
        usersDto.setActivationCode(user.getActivationCode());

        String emailText = Utils.createEmailText(usersDto, EmailType.USER_SIGN_UP.name());

        Utils.sendEmail(user.getUsername(), Constants.FROM_EMAIL, Constants.MAIL_SUBJECT_ACTIVATION_LINK, emailText);
    }

    return flag;
}
```

}

unfortunately the transaction is not being rollbacked, I have generated exception manually to reverse the transaction.
Any help in this regards?
TA.

Comment: does it work when uncommenting the commented code (`rollbackFor=Exception.class`)?

Comment: no, didn't worked, that's why commented out it

Comment: Wild guess. MySQL as the database with MyISAM as the storage engine. Also what is with the `@Transactional` which you aren't using at all (there is no `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your configuration.

Comment: Exactly, M. Deinum! whats the issue?

Comment: Do I need to add this? <tx:annotation-driven />

Comment: MyISAM doesn't support transactions, hence trying to rollback won't do anything. Switch to InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

Comment: shifted to InnoDB, but same issue

Comment: InnoDB plus uncommenting also doesn't work? I'm asking because by default rollbacks are only done for unchecked exceptions unless you provide the type. You're throwing a checked exception, which won't result in a rollback.

Comment: Yes uncommented the @Transaction annotation from method, and added <tx:annotation-driven /> as well, DB is now InnoDB, still not rollbacked. Is the issue is due to generating exception myself?

Comment: I am using OpenSessionInViewFilter as well, any luck?